# How to define commands error messages by BucketType

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I'm using max_concurrency twice for one command to limit invoking to 3 times max per guild, and one time max per user:

```
@commands.max_concurrency(3,per=commands.BucketType.guild,wait=False)
@commands.max_concurrency(1,per=commands.BucketType.user,wait=False)
async def start(self, ctx):
```

My question is how can I use the BucketType parameter to create separate error messages.

As an example of what I'm asking:

```
@start.error
async def on_command_error(self,ctx,error):

        if isinstance(error, commands.MaxConcurrencyReached):

              guild_error = "Too many playing"
              user_error = "You're already playing"

              await ctx.send("guild_error or user_error depending on BucketType?")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [MaxConcurrencyReached.per](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=concurrency#discord.ext.commands.MaxConcurrencyReached.per) attribute, we can find the BucketType and act accordingly.

For example:

```py
@start.error
async def on_command_error(self,ctx,error):

        if isinstance(error, commands.MaxConcurrencyReached):

              guild_error = "Too many playing"
              user_error = "You're already playing"
              # Because error.per returns a BucketType, we can check it against BucketType.user and BucketType.guild.
              if error.per == commands.BucketType.user:
                  await ctx.send(user_error)
              elif error.per == commands.BucketType.guild:
                  await ctx.send(guild_error)
```